# Why is my statically typed partial view trying to render an unintended model type?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have a partial view, in my ASP.NET MVC4 web app. It's just a partial view designed to display a table, given a collection of entities. It looks like this:

```
@model ICollection<Portal.Models.Matter>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Accessed</th>
            <th>Client</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @if (Model.Count > 0)
        {
            @Html.DisplayForModel()
        }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="text-muted text-centered">There are no Matters to display.</td>
            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a DisplayTemplate for `Matter` that is statically typed to the single `Matter` entity, and it handles rendering of each table row.

For some reason, when this partial is rendered, instead of using the `Matter` DisplayTemplate it just shows the following:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Portal.Models.Account]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Portal.Models.Account]
```

Now, this partial is not even bound to a collection of `Account` entities. It's bound to a collection of `Matter` entities. So, why is `@Html.DisplayForModel()` trying to display for a collection of `Account`s? At run time, using a debugger, I can see the `Model` is in fact a collection of `Matter` entities, not `Account`.

I render this partial using the following code:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Matter/_Table.cshtml", Model.Client.Matters, new ViewDataDictionary())
```

Comment: Why do you pass the Partial an empty `ViewDataDictionary`?

Comment: I was just testing it. With or without that, the same thing occurs.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a screenshot of all the files you have in your `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` folder?

Comment: Sure, [screen shot is here](http://i.imgur.com/PLFvlGS.png).

Comment: For partials to be used by other views, outside of the controller's named folder, do they have to be in the Shared folder?

Comment: Let me try to explain this as best I can. Say I have a View Model, `MyViewModel`. If I wanted to use `@Html.DisplayForModel()`, I would need to have a Partial View in my `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/` folder with the filename `MyViewModel.cshtml`. MVC is built to be able to automatically match up the type of your View Model with its corresponding Display Template, as long as the View Model's type name has the same name as the file in your `/DisplayTemplates` folder. The same concept applies to the `/EditorTemplates` folder, which is just as useful.

Comment: If you were to use `@Html.DisplayForModel()` on a View Model that does *not* have a template ready for use, MVC would automatically generate one based on every last property that the View Model has available, and it's usually laid out in a format that's less than preferable.

Comment: Also, now that I realize it, your Display Templates must *always* be in `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/`. Same for Editor Templates.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002059/asp-net-mvc-display-template-for-a-collection

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around, or maybe a solution, not sure. Anyway, instead of using `DisplayForModel` on an `ICollection`, I iterate over the collection and use `DisplayFor` on each element.

For example ...

```
@model ICollection<Foo>

for (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item)
}
```

I guess nothing is forcing you to use a property off of `m` in `DisplayFor`.