# Can I have a named display template for a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2, display-templates

I have a display for a collection of "SomeObject"

```
public List<SomeObject> SomeObjects

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SomeObjects)
```

This all works fine.. Then I had a requirement that meant I would need a second different display template for the same collection..

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SomeObjects, "NameOfTemplate")
```

I get the below message when I do this.. I have used named display templates before, but maybe it only works for primitive types - strings etc?

> `'System.Collections.Generic.List1[SomeObject]'`, but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type `'SomeObject'`.

**Adding code as request**

"Test" DisplayTemplate

```
@model ViewModels.SomeObject

<p class="Namme">
    <span>@Model.Name</span>
</p>
```

SimpleViewModel

```
 public class SomeObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Property in ParentViewModel

```
public List<SomeObject> SomeObjects { get; set; }
```

Cshtml file..

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SomeObjects, "Test")
```

To me its a simple question, can a named template be used with a collection or not? Is it another limitation of mvc..

Cheers,
John

Comment: Make sure the model in the Display template is of the same type your passing in via the DisplayFor razor extension. Seems like it isnt a generic list in your Display Template. For example in your template:
'@model IList<SomeObject>' opposed to '@model SomeObject'

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it didn't work. My understanding is that model for the displayTemplates should be the single and not the collection..

Here is what I tried and the error

@model IList<SomeObject>


HttpCompileException was unhandled by user code.
"External component has thrown an exception."

Comment: Can you post full code, including the Template. Basically whatever you are passing through via the Display For, that should be the model type for the Display Template. Try putting a '@Html.DisplayFor(m => m .SomeObjects.First(), "TemplateName")'. Seems like your just passing in the incorrect model type. Include the model code for the calling CSHTML page too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are passing a list of `SomeObject` to your display template, when it is expecting:

```
@model ViewModels.SomeObject
```

You either need to change the template to something like this and accept a list as the view model:

```
@model IList<ViewModels.SomeObject>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<p class="Namme">
    <span>@item</span>
</p>
}
```

Or change what you are passing into the Display Template in the parent CSHTML file and make it a single object of `SomeObject` something like this:

```
public List<SomeObject> SomeObjects

@foreach (var item in Model.SomeObjects) {
    Html.DisplayFor(item, "TemplateName")
}
```

Its hard to answer because im not sure what your trying to achieve, and what `SomeObject` is, but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks gdp.. Its a limitation of mvc so.. As passing the list(when not a named display template works fine, mvc does the looping for me) Once you use a named template, it will pass the collection, so yes the model will need to be the collection, hence needing the for loop within. Pointless to me so, as I had a for loop in my calling code, I was wanting to use the display template so that I could eliminate it. As mentions once Its not a named template it works fine.. ah well. live and learn :)

Comment: Its just that you had the incorrect model type in your custom Display Template. Changing this to a list in the template is what MVC will be doing anyway under the hood by solely using this: '@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyCollection)'.

Comment: true, but inside my template if I try and access the elements of the object I need the for loop.. what I wanted to avoid.. when its not a named template i dont need a loop. thats the main difference for me..

Comment: Yeh you cant avoid that unfortunately, if you want more granular control then you have to loop the model.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `SomObjects` is `List<SomeObjects>` so the view template must have a matching model:

```
@model `ICollection<ViewModels.SomeObject>`
```

I prefer to not restrict the view to the concrete `List<>` class but rather use an interface.

That also means that you have to adjust your template to use a loop to iterate through the items in the collection.

Comment: Anders, If I do that, I would need to iterate over it with a for loop. The point of me using the template was to remove the for loop from the calling page.. By putting the single Object as the model I dont need the loop and mvc takes care of the iterating.. This all works fine, until I try a named template which is what my question is about, as I have got many working with collections.. Related to this post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002059/asp-net-mvc-display-template-for-a-collection

Comment: The problem is that you can only tell MVC what template to use for the *entire collection* then it uses its internal logic to find the template for each item. If that is what you want to control you're probably out of luck as I don't know of a way to pass a display template to that second lookup step.