# Why Does Html.DisplayForModel() display only one item from list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I would like to display a list of items in a View using Html.DisplayModelFor().

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index() {

        var person = new ApplicationUser();
        person.Email = "Greg@gmail.com";
        person.UserName = "Greg";

        var person2 = new ApplicationUser();
        person.Email = "Gary@gmail.com";
        person.UserName = "Gary";

        var list = new List<ApplicationUser>();
        list.Add(person);
        list.Add(person2);

        return View(list);
    }
```

Here is the view:

```
@model  IEnumerable<WebApplication32.Models.ApplicationUser>


@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

Here is the DisplayTemplate named ApplicationUser:

```
@model WebApplication32.Models.ApplicationUser
<div>
  @Html.DisplayFor(u=> u.UserName)
  @Html.DisplayFor(u=> u.Email)
</div>
```

The result is only the first item being displayed.

If I change the view to:

```
@model  IEnumerable<WebApplication32.Models.ApplicationUser>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x)
}
```

Then each item is displayed.

But the second view makes no sense to me: In the foreach, 'item' does not appear to be used.  Yet it is looping through the items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002059/asp-net-mvc-display-template-for-a-collection

By the way, the method's name is `DisplayForModel()`, not `DisplayModelFor()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DisplayFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) expects *an expression that identifies the object that contains the properties to display*. The Model is already given by the HtmlHelper (=@Html). Therefor you don't need to use your item variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use model's itself:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <label>@item.UserName</label>
    <label>@item.Email</label>
}
```

Or one can use

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.Display(item.UserName)
}
```

Comment: Because the actual page has a number of different collections and I want to be able to use a DisplayTemplate/EditTemplate for each one.