# ASP.NET Display Templates - No output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this model:

```
public class DefinitionListModel : List<DefinitionListItemModel>
{
}
```

Then I have this display template (partial view) setup for it in DisplayTemplates:

```
@model Company.Product.Models.DefinitionListModel

<dl>
@foreach (var definition in Model)
{
    Html.DisplayFor(m => definition);
}
</dl>
```

Which calls this default display template because each item is a `DefinitionListItemModel`:

```
@model Company.Product.Models.DefinitionListItemModel

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Term, "DefinitionTerm");
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Description, "DefinitionDescription");
```

And the `DefinitionTerm` template looks like this:

```
@model object

@{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        string s = Model as string;
        if (s != null)
        {
            <dt>@s</dt>
        }
        else
        {
            // Other types and models that could be used.

            // Last resort.

            <dt>@Model.ToString()</dt>
        }
    }
}
```

A breakpoint placed in the last template is hit successfully and the view and mark-up appears to run through just fine, but none of it renders, not even the DL tag from the first template above.

Why does it hit breakpoints but not render any HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was all to do with semi-colons. It seems I can't just call `Html.DisplayFor` like a normal C# method with a semi-colon terminator.

For example, here's the revised `DefinitionListModel` template:

```
@model AcmeCo.Hudson.Models.DefinitionListModel

@if (Model != null)
{
    <dl>
        @foreach (var definition in Model)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => definition)
        }
    </dl>
}
```

Note the bizarre use of `@` within a code block that's already C#. I assume there's a proper way to do `DisplayFor` from within a C# block but I don't know what it is.

Comment: hi, will this also work with Edit Model? or do I need to reflect on the dataType?

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of the semicolon, it's because of the missing `@`. This is how `Razor` works. What's between curly brackets is not supposed to be `C#`. The `Razor` parser tries to figure out what's code and what's content. To begin a piece of code you have to set the `@` character. The `Razor` parser identifies everything between braces as content.

Check out [Scott's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx) for some very good examples.

Comment: I don't think that's right, but I'll wait for some votes to come in.

Comment: Why not? Have you checked out Scott's blog? What are your concerns?

Comment: Well, simply because I use code all the time that has immediately more C# in the braces of an `if` block in a Razor view.